# Нужно, чтобы приложение запускалось только через лаунчер

Tags: c#

В общем, есть два ексешника. Один лаунчер и один стандартный для запуска приложения. Нужно чтобы запускалось ТОЛЬКО с лаунчера, чтобы ексешник вообще не работал, а лучше чтобы его не существовало. Есть одна загвоздка, доступа к исходному коду ексешника нету, только мой лаунчер который я могу вертеть как хочу. Мне пришла в голову весьма странная идея скачивать при запуске ексешник (без инета прога не будет работать априори) но это как минимум странно и даже звучит глупо. Так что прошу вашей помощи с этим вопросом. Повторю. Нужно, чтобы приложение запускалось только через лаунчер. Доступа к исходному коду приложения которое должно запускаться нету. Есть ли какие-нибудь обходные пути этого? Мне кажется, что это даже звучит абсурдно, но вдруг...

Comment: Помню сервер Lineage 2 делал и там надо было сделать примерно такую же задачу - заставить человека запустить лаунчер, дабы он обновил клиент игры. 90% людей мы смогли заставить запустить лаунчер путем банального переименования файла запуска с `.exe` на `.bin`, файл как бы есть, но для многих людей это неведомая пустышка, а если его сделать еще и скрытым, так вообще). Другие же 10% страдали без обновлений, увы, были умники. Тут есть конечно много своих "НО", но я без понятия что конкретно вы решаете, если не можете даже сменить запускаемый файл, то наверно подобное сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Если есть контроль над исходниками второго экзешника - можно параметром принимать какой-нибудь секретный ключ без которого происходит моментальный выход из программы. А ланчер будет запускать этот экзешник с этим ключом.

Comment: Еще дополнительно лаунчером можно установить Mutex, и запускаться только если Mutex лаунчера найден. Так же можно ставить свой Mutex и защититься этим же способом от повторного запуска нескольких копий приложения.